# Zybooks 5.19 LAB: Golf scores

Tags: python

I am having problems with writing a Python code for my Zybooks Lab and need some help. Here is the question.

> Golf scores record the number of strokes used to get the ball in the hole. The expected number of strokes varies from hole to hole and is called par (i.e. 3, 4, or 5). Each score's name is based on the actual strokes taken compared to par:
>
> - "Eagle": number of strokes is two less than par
> - "Birdie": number of strokes is one less than par
> - "Par": number of strokes equals par
> - "Bogey": number of strokes is one more than par
>
> Given two integers that represent par and the number of strokes used, write a program that prints the appropriate score name. Print "Error" if par or score is not in the expected range.

I have looked for help and their are answers to the question. However, they are using characters I have not used yet and do not want to get in trouble for using them. Or written in C+.

```
strokes = int(input())
par = int(input())
    
if (par != 3 and par != 4 and par != 5:
     print('Error')
     
elif (strokes <= par - 2):
     print('Eagle')
elif (strokes <= par -1):
      print('Birdie')
elif (strokes == par):
     print('Par')
else:
    print('Bogey')
```

these are the answers I am getting.

```
1. Input
4 
3
Your output
Par
Expected output
Birdie

2. Input
5 
3
Your output
Par
Expected output
Eagle

3. Input
5 
5
Your output
Par                (correct)

4.Input
5 
6
Your output
Par
Expected output
Bogey

5:Input
1 
2
Your output
Error              (correct)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, but there's no question here and it's not clear what exactly you need help with. Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). See also [ask] in general, for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: To be clear, this code has an obvious syntax error and it doesn't produce that output, that's why it's not clear what you need help with. Although, if there are typos, you can [edit] to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same class preparing for the final.

Try to break down the problem into smaller parts and type out each part you understand. Then work on understanding and combinig the other parts of the problem.

It may seem obvious, but trial and error have been my greatest help. I type things in and see what happens, and learn from that.

I've realised that coding isn't a quickly-learned skill and that by breaking and fixing my code, I've learned A LOT.

This is nothing more than my opinion, based on my experience as a novice programmer, and I hope it helps.

My Solution:

EDITED:

```
par = int(input())
strokes = int(input())


if par not in range(3, 6):
    print('Error')
elif (par - strokes) < -1:
    print('Error')

if par - strokes == 2:
    print('Eagle')
elif par - strokes == 1:
    print('Birdie')
elif par == strokes:
    print('Par')
elif par - strokes == -1:
    print('Bogey')
```